# How to save content from Mozilla developer network (javascript guide) for offline viewing?

Tags: javascript, firefox-developer-tools

The links provided by MDN on its website gives me older version of the guide which is not well organized.

The guide i want to download is this one.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MDN/About#Downloading_content for a full tarball of MDN (8GB) , https://zealdocs.org/ for an offline browser and https://kapeli.com/mdn_offline for some extracts

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded them earlier and they show a different version than the one shown in the current website.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using HTTrack. Here is [Homepage](http://www.httrack.com)

Official Description :
It allows you to download a World Wide Web site from the Internet to a local directory, building recursively all directories, getting HTML, images, and other files from the server to your computer. HTTrack arranges the original site's relative link-structure. Simply open a page of the "mirrored" website in your browser, and you can browse the site from link to link, as if you were viewing it online. HTTrack can also update an existing mirrored site, and resume interrupted downloads. HTTrack is fully configurable, and has an integrated help system.